# scroll text over fixed image

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position, caption

Hi I am trying to implement caption scroll like this site [link](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2018/10/26/world/middleeast/saudi-arabia-war-yemen.html?smid=fb-nytimes&smtyp=cur&fbclid=IwAR1FCwfT2FXAnx6zeudNd1BhMTGVxxy7UCBCABBwgXUMS-PjJIclHBHeNLo)

Here when image will get it will set on that position and caption will scroll. when caption scroll will complete. it again scroll body to next div.

I tried with below code but here it's not getting same as I want.

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
   var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    return ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    
    if (isScrolledIntoView('.box')) {
        $('img').addClass('animated flip').css('background', 'red');
        //added background red so you can see it has triggered
    }
    else {
    $('img').removeClass('animated flip');
    }
    
});
```

```css
.col-md-12 {
    height: 1500px;
    padding-top: 1000px;
}
.animated {
      opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity 1s 0s, visibility 1s 0s;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.rad-slideshow-item {
    position: relative;
}
.rad-slideshow-item .rad-asset-wrapper {
 
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animated .rad-slideshow-item.active-adjacent div.rad-asset-wrapper {
background: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
 }
.animated .rad-slideshow-item.active-adjacent div.rad-asset-wrapper {
  display: block;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transition: opacity 0s 1s, visibility 0s 1s;
}
.rad-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-Sticky-Sidebar-With-jQuery/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 ">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x800" class="icon"/>
        <div class="rad-slideshow-item active-adjacent">
         
          <div class="rad-asset-wrapper">
            <h1>WEB<br/>DESIGN</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/nvo2b4ku/)

Comment: I think it uses javascript's onscroll event. Its jsut fixed background. if (scrolltop == (background's top offset)){fix background}

Comment: @TrueTiem can u give me any sample in fiddle so I can try

Comment: @TrueTiem I fixed image when image get on scroll. now just need to scrollable caption on image.